# Problem with some missing values with re module

Tags: python, text-parsing

I'm currently working on a parsing function using regular expressions, but the function that I wrote can't currently handle missing data. The code I'm using is based on the code on https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/ and is parsing a structured text fields with every line in the form of:

*someField = someValue*

This files I parse could by construction have some fields which have no value in *someValue*.
Since I construct afterwards a row, like in the link, how can i handle the missing values if the file I parse doesn't contain any value for a certain field?

EDIT:

I'll make a case example. Say the .txt files I need to parse contain this two fields:

Height=176

Weight=75.9

and using this part of the code only:

```
import os
import re 
import pandas as pd



def parse_line(line, curr_dict):
    """
    The function parse_line(line) does a parse on the input line. This function is taken from the tutorial on parsing files available at https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/ 
    """
    for key, rx in curr_dict.items():
        match = rx.search(line)
        if match:
            return key, match
    # if there are no matches
    return None, None

test_dict={
    'Weight' : re.compile(r'Weight=(?P<Weight>\d+[.]\d+)\n'),
    'Height' : re.compile(r'Height=(?P<Height>\d+)\n'), 
}

with open(txt_file,'r') as f:
        new_line = f.readline()
        while new_line:
            key, match = parse_line(new_line, test_dict)
            if key :
                if key == 'Weight':
                    Weight = match.group('Weight')
                    Weight = float(Weight)
                if key == 'Height':
                    Height = match.group('Height')
            new_line = f.readline()
row = {'Height' : Height,
       'Weight' : Weight,
      }
df = pd.DataFrame(row, index=[1])
```

If all fields are complete in the file, as shown above, there are no problems, but if for example:

Height=

Weight=75.9

I have an error because I have a missing value in Height=

Comment: Can you please post the code you've written so far; optimally along with some exemplary input to have a MWE at hand?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Vote to close because the code in your question is not a [mre]. Given that Python code is very dependent on indenting, please fix your code in the question so it is executable. I need to be able to copy/paste what you provide into a file and run it, and you need to include an example of the data your code processes. If that means not reading a file but using a variable, that’s what you need to include in your question. We need a [mre].

Comment: @barny I have modified the code, I think this is minimal, the only thing missing is a txt file with the data, that for the new example you just need to copy/paste in a txt file

Comment: @Gabriel sorry, I didn't realize it when i wrote that example :(

Comment: Seems to me that your code is not in any way minimal - surely the key problem is matching the “value=“ case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `someValue` is just blank when it's missing, you just have to add a `?` after the groups corresponding to the `someValue` fields.

A random example of what it would look like from the ones you provided:

`re.compile(r'Weight=(?P<Weight>\d+[.]\d+)?\n')`

Notice the exclamation mark before the newline character.

In case it's actually a space instead of being just blank, try

`re.compile(r'Weight=(?P<Weight>\d+[.]\d+)? ?\n')`

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> `?`
>
> Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. `ab?` will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.

Considering the match will be `None` when the value is blank, you should also add a value check to your code:

```
if key :
    if key == 'Weight':
        Weight = match.group('Weight')
        if Weight is not None:
            Weight = float(Weight)
        else:
            Weight = 0.0
        
    if key == 'Height':
        Height = match.group('Height')
        if Height is not None:
            Height = float(Height)
        else:
            Height = 0.0
```

Comment: This solution resolves in part the problem. I mean the value is matched with either a blank space or a newline character, but since I then convert the type to float (or integer) for numbers (this are basically the only data that could be missing). I still have a problem.

Comment: @alegiac edited my answer to include what you should do. just beware when trying to convert values that might be `None`.

Comment: @Gabriel- I tried your updates in my function and I've got this error as a result: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType`

Comment: @alegiac are you trying to convert `Height` as well? if so, check if it is `None` as well.

Comment: yes I am but I'm testing with just weight missing. After that I'll generalize.

Comment: check your code anywhere you're trying to convert a value to float, and check if it is `None`. the example you provided should be working with the change i made.

Comment: I've double-checked and the above error appears only when the RE expression matches a `'\n'` or a`' '` otherwise it works with no errors

Comment: @Gabriel I think alegiac wants/needs you to solve every single little problem with their code. You may want to let alegiac actually do some work for themselves.